# unable to enable php-gmp for php7.4 with ddev

Tags: php, linux, debian, php-7, ddev

Because of this error message `the requested PHP extension gmp is missing from your system`
I want to add the *gmp extension* to php 7.4 using **DDEV**.

First I made a `.ddev/php/` folder and created a `99-gmp.ini` file.
Second I added `extension=php_gmp.so` to `99-gmp.ini`

I ssh login `ddev ssh` and run:

`sudo apt install php-gmp`

`sudo apt-get install php-gmp`

`sudo apt-get install php7.4-gmp`
And tried a few variants but the package isn't found

searching for `apt search php-gmp` results in:

`Reading package lists... DoneBuilding dependency tree Reading state information... Done E: Unable to locate package php-gmp`

`apt search gmp` results in 3 packages, all installed already:

`Full Text Search... Done`

libgmp10/now 2:6.1.2+dfsg-4 amd64 [installed,local]
Multiprecision arithmetic library

libhogweed4/now 3.4.1-1 amd64 [installed,local]
low level cryptographic library (public-key cryptos)

libnettle6/now 3.4.1-1 amd64 [installed,local]
low level cryptographic library (symmetric and one-way cryptos)

Looking for php7.4 extentions:
`apt search php7.4`
***For some reason `gmp` isn't found?***

`Sorting... Done Full Text Search... Done`

libapache2-mod-php7.4/now 7.4.8-1+0~20200713.23+debian10~1.gbpb2c15c amd64 [installed,local]
server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (Apache 2 module)

php7.4-bcmath/now 7.4.8-1+0~20200713.23+debian10~1.gbpb2c15c amd64 [installed,local]
Bcmath module for PHP

php7.4-bz2/now 7.4.8-1+0~20200713.23+debian10~1.gbpb2c15c amd64 [installed,local]
bzip2 module for PHP

php7.4-cgi/now 7.4.8-1+0~20200713.23+debian10~1.gbpb2c15c amd64 [installed,local]
server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (CGI binary)

php7.4-cli/now 7.4.8-1+0~20200713.23+debian10~1.gbpb2c15c amd64 [installed,local]
command-line interpreter for the PHP scripting language

php7.4-common/now 7.4.8-1+0~20200713.23+debian10~1.gbpb2c15c amd64 [installed,local]
documentation, examples and common module for PHP

php7.4-curl/now 7.4.8-1+0~20200713.23+debian10~1.gbpb2c15c amd64 [installed,local]
CURL module for PHP

php7.4-fpm/now 7.4.8-1+0~20200713.23+debian10~1.gbpb2c15c amd64 [installed,local]
server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (FPM-CGI binary)

php7.4-gd/now 7.4.8-1+0~20200713.23+debian10~1.gbpb2c15c amd64 [installed,local]
GD module for PHP

php7.4-intl/now 7.4.8-1+0~20200713.23+debian10~1.gbpb2c15c amd64 [installed,local]
Internationalisation module for PHP

php7.4-json/now 7.4.8-1+0~20200713.23+debian10~1.gbpb2c15c amd64 [installed,local]
JSON module for PHP

php7.4-ldap/now 7.4.8-1+0~20200713.23+debian10~1.gbpb2c15c amd64 [installed,local]
LDAP module for PHP

php7.4-mbstring/now 7.4.8-1+0~20200713.23+debian10~1.gbpb2c15c amd64 [installed,local]
MBSTRING module for PHP

php7.4-mysql/now 7.4.8-1+0~20200713.23+debian10~1.gbpb2c15c amd64 [installed,local]
MySQL module for PHP

php7.4-opcache/now 7.4.8-1+0~20200713.23+debian10~1.gbpb2c15c amd64 [installed,local]
Zend OpCache module for PHP

php7.4-pgsql/now 7.4.8-1+0~20200713.23+debian10~1.gbpb2c15c amd64 [installed,local]
PostgreSQL module for PHP

php7.4-phpdbg/now 7.4.8-1+0~20200713.23+debian10~1.gbpb2c15c amd64 [installed,local]
server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (PHPDBG binary)

php7.4-readline/now 7.4.8-1+0~20200713.23+debian10~1.gbpb2c15c amd64 [installed,local]
readline module for PHP

php7.4-soap/now 7.4.8-1+0~20200713.23+debian10~1.gbpb2c15c amd64 [installed,local]
SOAP module for PHP

php7.4-sqlite3/now 7.4.8-1+0~20200713.23+debian10~1.gbpb2c15c amd64 [installed,local]
SQLite3 module for PHP

php7.4-xml/now 7.4.8-1+0~20200713.23+debian10~1.gbpb2c15c amd64 [installed,local]
DOM, SimpleXML, XML, and XSL module for PHP

php7.4-xmlrpc/now 7.4.8-1+0~20200713.23+debian10~1.gbpb2c15c amd64 [installed,local]
XMLRPC-EPI module for PHP

php7.4-zip/now 7.4.8-1+0~20200713.23+debian10~1.gbpb2c15c amd64 [installed,local]
Zip module for PHP

### Project Information

PHP version:            7.4
OS:                     Debian 10
NFS mount enabled:      false
Database type:          mariadb
MariaDB version:        10.3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually, you should add packages through adding `webimage_extra_packages` to your configuration (see the [documentation](https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/extend/customizing-images/)):

```
webimage_extra_packages: [php7.4-gmp]
```

On restarting the containers using `ddev restart`, this configuration is applied and the package gets installed. Have you tried this?

Using this way helps to keep this package tied to the container ddev uses. While adding it to a running container (as you did) is not explicitly wrong, this package will be removed again if you change the PHP version or upgrade ddev. Through using the configuration, you can ensure that this package is installed again if the container images change.

Comment: nice this was the trick. I was to fixated on https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/extend/customization-extendibility/#providing-custom-php-configuration-phpini

Comment: @Joehoe that's something you can do additionally if you **need** to change the configuration. I would recommend to use the default configuration first, once again to keep changes as little as possible